# Drarry Veela courtship Harry Potter fan fiction

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I read this story late last year and it was very good. I'm looking to read it again but can't find it.

Harry is a Veela and holds a contest for possible mates. The Quibbler sets up interviews with him because it's very public. Harry defies Dumbledore, and ends up picking Draco not knowing it's him. There is something about dark elves, Harry’s grandfather on his mothers side, and I think I read it on Wattpad but that isn’t certain.

Comment: Is there a heavy "dominant - submissive" factor to the Veela heritage?

Answer (score 1):

This might be vvc's "[Desperate Measures](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4228464/1/Desperate-Measures)", which [villian123 republished on Wattpad](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4228464/1/Desperate-Measures) (along  with vvc's other stories).

> Harry may be a half-Veela, but there was no such thing as a destined mate. If somebody wanted him, they would have to prove their worthiness. And Draco’s chances don't look so good when Harry guts him at the welcoming feast… HPDM, mpreg

Chapter One has him defying Dumbledore by making his Veela heritage, and subsequent courtship, public, rather than the private matter Dumbledore would prefer, and gutting Draco (he gets better) for unwanted advances and claiming it was valid and legal behavior. He's backed by the "Veela Accords" which more or less come down to that the Wizarding World can't interfere with Veela affairs. Chapter Two has him describing the process of courtship, which consists of people sending him gifts. Chapter Three has him doing an interview with the Quibbler. And indeed, from the tagging of the story and some of the comments, he does wind up picking Draco despite the early rejection, due to Draco really getting him when it comes to the courtship.

Not matching, there's nothing about dark elves that I can find.

Found with a search for *site:wattpad.com harry veela quibbler contest*